# Github no changes are being showed after massive push

Tags: git, github, npm, cmd

I used the following commands to update my web portfolio:

```bash
git init
git remote add origin "GITHUB LINK"
git add .
git commit -m "VERSION 0.0.0.0"
git push --set-upstream origin master  || git push origin
```

But it is showing no changes in the repository but it does show this:
[image: github]

When I click the compare and pull request the entire code is present but why isnt it updating in the repository?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pushed to a branch called `master`, but your repository's default branch is called `main`. That's the default setting for GitHub repositories; the default for `git init` is `master`, but you can configure that with the [`init.defaultBranch` setting](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-initdefaultBranch).

You have to pick either of the two, and then remove the other one.